# React Datepicker returning the wrong ID when being clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

I am trying to save the values of two Date Pickers into a variable, so I can then calculate the difference between the two dates. Currently the DatePicker is receiving id from the App.tsx, and the idea is to return this ID back to the main app once the DatePicker is clicked, so I can save the results into different variables. However, the DatePicker function keeps returning that the first DatePicker is being clicked and not the second one, and I'm not exactly sure why. Here's the code for the DatePicker

```
    export const DatePickerBasicExample = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<Date | null | undefined>(null);
  const [id, setID] = React.useState<Date | null | undefined>(null);

  const onSelectDate = (date: Date | null | undefined): void => {
    setValue(date);
    const clickedID = id;
    props.getData(clickedID, date);
  };

  const getClickedElement = (e) => {
    setID(e.target.id);
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.datepicker}>
      <DatePicker
        id={props.id}
        className={controlClass.control}
        formatDate={(date: Date): string => {
          return  date.getDate()  + '.' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '.' + (date.getFullYear() );
        }}
        label={props.label}
        isRequired={false}
        allowTextInput={true}
        firstDayOfWeek={firstDayOfWeek}
        strings={DayPickerStrings}
        value={value!}
        onClick={getClickedElement}
        // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-bind
        onSelectDate={onSelectDate}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is the function that saves the data into variables. The console.log is just for troubleshooting, and the ID of "StartDatum" gets returned each time, regardless of which element I click on

```
  getData = (id, data) => {
    if (id="StartDatum"){
      Date1 =  data;
      console.log(id);
    } else {
      Date2 = data;
      console.log(id);
    }
    console.log(Date1);
    console.log(Date2);
  }
```

I have tried many different ways of updating the id of the Datepicker, and none seems to be working. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please change `if (id="StartDatum")` to  `if (id=="StartDatum")`

Comment: OMG, that was it! 2 hours gone on an equal sign! Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. Have a nice day.